# Equation that, when the input increases by a factor of 10, the growth rate of the output increases exponentially

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I did some performance testing on one of our pipelines at work, feeding in batches of records at increasing factors of 10. I noticed that at every increase, the growth rate of the runtime approximately doubled. This is a bit easier to see in this sample data:

| Input size ($X$) | Runtime ($Y$) | Runtime Growth ($Y_{n+1}/Y_n$) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |
| 100 | 2 | 4 |
| 1000 | 8 | 8 |
| 10000 | 64 | 16 |
| 100000 | 1024 | 32 |
| 1000000 | 32768 | null (would be 64) |

I noticed that this recurrence relation holds true:

Define growth rate $G_n = Y_{n+1}/Y_n$

${G_n} ^ {1/log_{10}(X_n)} = 2$

I'm really curious how I could represent $Y$ in terms of $X$, or at the very least get a better sense of the runtime complexity.

Comment: The following function calculates the Y-values: $$Y(X)=\large{2^{\frac{\log_{10}(X)\cdot \left( \log_{10}(X)-1\right)}{2}}}$$ *Numerical example*: $Y(10^6)=2^{\frac{\log_{10}(10^6)\cdot \left( \log_{10}(10^6)-1\right)}{2}}=2^{\frac{6\cdot 5}{2}}=2^{15}=32768$

Comment: Wow! Thank you that's really interesting